# getting modelbound object property in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

My viewmodel contains a list of objects that I'm iterating through, and each one has a certain class associated with them. My goal is on click of that item to open it up to view, but I'm unclear on how to get the id of that row in my jquery click function.

```
            foreach (var item in Model.PatientViewModel)
            {
                    <div class="patientBox patientBox-unselected">
                        <h7>
                            <div class="pvb-mrn">MRN: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MRN)</div>
                            <div class="pvb-dob">DOB: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DOB)</div>
                            <br />
                            <div class="pvb-link">
                                @Html.ActionLink("Update Patient >", "Edit", new { id = item.PatientID })
                            </div>
                        </h7>
                    </div>
            }
```

and then my script with a test alert just to ensure i was hitting the function, which works fine, but how can I get the ID of the clicked item here?

```
    $('.patientBox').click(function () {
        window.location.href("/View/" + @item.ID);
    })
```

view model:

```
public class PatientScreenViewModel
{
    public List<PatientDTO> PatientViewModel { get; set; }

    public PatientSearchDTO SearchViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `item.ID` in html Attribute and get it with `jQuery` like so:

```
foreach (var item in Model.PatientViewModel){
   <div class="patientBox patientBox-unselected" data-item-id="<%= item.ID %>">
                   ...
                   ...
   </div>
}
```

*jQuery:*

```
$('.patientBox').click(function () {
    window.location.href("/View/" + this.getAttribute('data-item-id');
})
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, can't believe I forgot about that. Thank you!